# Saving camera picture in a file, file not created

Tags: android, android-camera

In my application I need to save a picture of the camera when the user presses the camera view. So far so good, I followed the official tutorial : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html and everything works fine except when I try to save the picture in the callback. Indeed, I get no error in the try/catch block but my file is nowhere to be found.

I have add the correct permissions in the mannifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

In my callback I have :

```
  private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() 
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
        {
            Log.d("tag", "Je rentre bien dans la callback");

            //File pictureFile = media.getOutputMediaFile( MediaFile.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE );
            File pictureFile =  new File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "temp.png");


            if (pictureFile == null)
            {
                Log.d("tag", "Error creating media file, check storage permissions ");
                return;
                }

            try 
            {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( pictureFile );
                Log.d("tag", "Fichier créer : " + pictureFile.getAbsolutePath() );
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                Log.d("tag", "File not found " + pictureFile.getAbsolutePath() 
                        + " Readable : " + pictureFile.canRead()
                        + " Writeable : " + pictureFile.canWrite()
                        + " Exist : " + pictureFile.exists() );
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.d("tag", "Error accessing file");
            }
        }
```

My log file show my this :

```
    04-03 10:29:28.950: D/tag(15087): Je rentre bien dans la callback
    04-03 10:29:28.960: D/tag(15087): Fichier créer : /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/temp.png
```

I check the sdcard in the tablet, but like I said the file is nowhere to be found. I research my problem, but I haven't find anything usefull yet.
I don't see what's wrong with my code or what's missing.

I hope someone here can help me.

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this

```
System.gc();
String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg"; //you can give any name to your image file
String mPathImage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/" + fileName;
File file = new File(mPathImage);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mIntent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
startActivityForResult(mIntent, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing.

```
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ getResources().getString(R.string.QRCode_Path));
    path.mkdirs();
```

Main thing is `path.mkdirs();` it will create a folder even if not created and then file will be saved.

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't change a ,thing the file is still save nowhere. It didtn't even created the directory. I am in a fragment when I'm doing the save I don't know if it changes something. I edit my log it says :
         04-03 15:48:29.000: D/tag(18524): Fichier créer /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/temp.png Readable : true Writeable : true Exist : true